# Chrome Wait For Completion

Tags: javascript, callback, google-chrome-extension

(I think that this is a callback issue, but I'm not completely sure)

I have a function that wants to retrieve data from all tabs. It looks like:

```
function retrieveData(callback) {
    getAllTabs(function(openedTabs) {
        for(var t=0; t<openedTabs.length; t++) {
            //get data from this tab
        }
    });
    //log(look at updated data)
}

function getAllTabs(callback) {
    if(callback) {
        chrome.windows.getAll({populate: true}, function(windows) { 
            //get tabs from windows; callback(tabs)
        });
    }
}
```

My problem is not that I don't get the data from the tabs. That works fine. It's that if I call retrieveData, the functions occur in an order s.t. I don't get the data until after I've already left function retrieveData, i.e. if I look at my data right where that log statement is in getAllTabs, there are no updates. 
How do I fix this so that the data is there in a sequential order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I quite understand the phrasing of the problem, but I think the problem is that you're dealing with asynchronous requests not synchronous requests. When you call `chrome.windows.getAll`, the function does not return all the tabs right away. Instead, you're saying to Google Chrome: *"I want all the tabs, but don't give it too me right away. When you have all the tabs, run this callback function"*.

If you want to run `log(look at updated data)` sequentially after getting all the tabs, you should put it inside the callback function you pass to `getAllTabs`

```
function retrieveData(callback) {
    getAllTabs(function(openedTabs) {
        for(var t=0; t<openedTabs.length; t++) {
            //get data from this tab
        }
        //log(look at updated data)
    });
}
```